# A dynamic include action for a DbSet is not getting applied

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get a method in my base repository to allow includes dynamically.  Consider the following direct version of what I want:

```
public async Task<IList<Presentation>> All()
{
    return await DbSet
        .Include(x => x.Questions)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

That function works as expected - the `Questions` get included in the result.

Now consider this method in the base repository:

```
public virtual async Task<IPagedList<TEntity>> AllAsync(int? page, int? pageSize, Action<IQueryable<TEntity>> includeAction = null)
{
    var index = page ?? 1;
    var size = pageSize ?? 25;
    var skipRows = (index - 1) * size;

    var queryable = DbSet.Skip(skipRows).Take(size);
    includeAction?.Invoke(queryable);

    var items = await queryable.ToListAsync();
    return new PagedList<TEntity>(index, size, items);
}
```

I call it like this:

```
functionResult.Presentations = await presentationRepository.AllAsync(request.Page, null, set => set.Include(x => x.Questions));
```

From my vantage point, I am doing the same thing, but for some reason, the `Questions` aren't included in that result.

**NOTE:** I have tried moving the `.Skip(skipRows).Take(size)` to the `queryable` section such that the `Include` is only applied to the `DbSet`, like this, and there is no change in outcome.

```
var items = await queryable.Skip(skipRows).Take(size).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Include` returns a new queryable so it needs to be a `Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>>`, not an `Action<IQueryable<TEntity>>`. For example:

```
public virtual async Task<IPagedList<TEntity>> AllAsync(int? page, int? pageSize, 
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>> includeFunc = null)
{
    var index = page ?? 1;
    var size = pageSize ?? 25;
    var skipRows = (index - 1) * size;

    var queryable = DbSet.Skip(skipRows).Take(size);

    if(includeFunc != null)
    {
        queryable = includeFunc(queryable);
    }

    var items = await queryable.ToListAsync();
    return new PagedList<TEntity>(index, size, items);
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!  I will accept as soon as it is available.

Comment: Side note, this method is a little dangerous since it lets the caller pretty much do anything with the queryable, include return a completely new one.

Comment: That's a really good observation, I'll review it with my team, but I think its usage is isolated and secure enough to support it.